# Multiple textboxes fill the dropdown selection having same class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have used the concept of multiple textboxes having same class fill with the multiple dropdown option selection which also having same class.I have facing problems in it.when i click the first dropdown option then it change the second textbox value.I want that if i click on first dropdown option it changes the values of first textbox not other or if click the second dropdown option it will change the value of second textbox.

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
    <select name="drop[]" id="budget" class="drop"> 
        <option value="1">option1</option> 
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option> 
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" class="txt" value="text1"><br> 
    <select name="drop[]" id="budget1" class="drop"> 
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option> 
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="txt" id="txt1" class="txt" value="text2">

</form>
```

```js
$('input[name="txt"]').each(function () { 
    $('.drop').on('change', function(){
        var total = $(this).val();
        $('input[name="txt"]').val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value")); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out the **next input element** which should be updated when you change a select element. You can use the below code to achieve this.

```
    $('.drop').on('change', function(){
        var total = $(this).val();
        $(this).next("input:first").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value")); 
    });
```

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/qFjuFtwhHBvDE9zxAup2?p=preview

Comment: @babi glad to help :)

Comment: I want to ask a one more question from you if i have three textboxes in after dropdown and dropdown and textboxes are dynamically created using php.The textbox value i want to change  value from the selection of dropdown  option is third textbox for example one dropdown and there are three textboxes in it.

Comment: for example :- i have a script code :-     $(".drop").on('change', function(){
     var $this = $(this),
     selectBox = $this.val();
    $(this).next("input:first").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value")); )};   myphp code is <td><input type='text' id='newhiddenBox'class='newhiddenBox' value='".$a."'></td>  
    <td><input  type='text' value='".$a."'  class='textbox tt form-control' id='textbox'></td>

    <td><input  type='hidden' value='".$a."'  class='textbox1 form-control' id='textbox1'></td>

Comment: update the plunker as per your requirement  https://plnkr.co/edit/qFjuFtwhHBvDE9zxAup2?p=preview

Comment: Important thing is you need to use event delegation for the dynamically created elements. Let me know in case you need more details

Comment: thankyou sir for help if i use select tag in table format then it does not work for table tag.please see it https://plnkr.co/edit/g1298pvJXsacgFaJCwI2?p=preview. i have updated the code .it does not work.

Comment: yes, since now you have put input element inside a td element, the previous selectors will no work anymore, i have updated the  answer here . https://plnkr.co/edit/aQ7j97czogviK3kuhCRW

Comment: Thankyou  so much sir for helping me again  it works. :)